# pass two different variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is my javascript of first page

```
 <script>
        function MessageDetailsById(id)
        {
            $("#active"+id).css({"color":"red"});
            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
             var url = "Ajax.php";
             var adm = "<?php echo $admno; ?>";
            var params = "Id="+id;"adm="+adm;
            http.open("POST", url, true);
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            //alert(http.responseText);
                        }
        }

            http.send(params);

            window.location.href="#";


        }

        </script>
```

this is the coding of ajax.php

```
<?php
include("model.php");
$DB=new database;

if(isset($_POST["Id"]))
{
    $DB->updateMassageTitleStauts($_POST["Id"],$_POST["adm"]);

}
else
{
    header("Location:index.php?ajaxmas=wHgfghks^^%&fnjfskjdfb");
}
?>
```

i want to send one variable of php and another is id of a div... how to send two parameters and recieves them on other side ??? please correct this code in details i am not expert ???

Comment: You can open your browser's developer console with F12 in order to see the syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the post data encoding:

```
var params = "Id=" + id + "&adm=" + adm;
```

Use `&` for separator.